# Windows Server Fundation 2012 - Maximum number of users

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

We are going to buy a IBM server with Windows Server Foundation 2012 R2.

According to this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679892.aspx there is "Maximum number of users" equal 15. I'm not sure for what kind users this limitation applies. I gave some thought to it, and I came with:

- My 1st guess is: this is limitation of global OS users count - 15 users in WinSrvF2012 = I can create up to 15 users/accounts in system.
- My next guess is: this is maximum number of users logged locally/remotely (RDP) - so I can have more accounts than 15 in system but simultaneously there can be no more than 15 users connected/logged on server.
- My last guess is: this is "global" maximum simultaneously logged users by SAMBA shares + local + RDP sessions - of course I know of SAMBA max connection count (=30) and RDP sessions ("Maximum number of Remote Desktop Services (RDS) Gateway connections"=50(?!)).

Answer (score 0):

Limits are there and it depends upon each editions.

Yes, as stated you can have only 15 user accounts on foundation edition, and essential edition is limited to 75 user account. But the STD and Datacenter editions does not have any such limits.

Read more from [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2012/12/12/using-windows-server-2012-essentials-with-more-than-25-users.aspx) & [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2012/08/06/growing-beyond-25-users-with-windows-server-2012-essentials.aspx).

Comment: Ok, then let me ask this: 1. How many connection via RDP I can have in Foundation 2012? 2. To raise this (RDP connections) I need CALs am I right? 3. How many users can be connected to SAMBA shares? I mean simultaneous connection.